# Express checkout API authentication fields in magento-1.9 disappeared

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

Paypal express checkout API authentication field box not showing. Here is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/NovsO.jpg (marked box is not showing from magento-1.9 admin )
[image]

Comment: No body hasn't any idea about it?